# Toggle show hide div on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hee,

Im trying to toggle multiple divs based on its parent checkbox value.

It just doesn't seem to work. Probably a rookie mistake! Can you help me out?

HTML:

```
<li><input class="yourCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /><label>Type zaak</label></li>
    <div id="1" style="display:none;">          
        <label class="marginleft20" for="invTypeRegeling">Type zaak<strong> *</strong></label>          
        <select multiple="multiple">
            <option>Bezwaar</option>
            <option>Beroep</option>
            <option>Administratief beroep</option>
            <option>Proforma beroep</option>
            <option>Proforma hoger beroep</option>
            <option>Hoger beroep-dept. verweerder</option>
            <option>Hoger beroep-dept. appelland </option>
            <option>Voorlopige voorziening</option>
            <option>Rechtstreeks beroep</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".yourCheckbox").click(function(){
       $("#"+$(this).val()).toggle();
   });
]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sentah/o1mjxfm6/

Comment: You have a syntax error - the closing `]` should be a `}`. Other than that, your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/o1mjxfm6/4/

Comment: You forgot to add jquery library in ur fiddle with small syntax error http://jsfiddle.net/o1mjxfm6/20/

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things:

1. your fiddle wasn't including jQuery
2. your sytax for the function ended in a `]` instead of `}`
3. your binding on a checkbox should be `.change()` instead of `.click()`

https://jsfiddle.net/o1mjxfm6/18/